# Change DataField Attribute in a Gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewAllPeopleEditMode" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
    AllowPaging="true" 
    PageSize="20"
    OnRowEditing="GridViewAllPeopleEditMode_RowEditing" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridViewAllPeopleEditMode_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowUpdating="GridViewAllPeopleEditMode_RowUpdating"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewAllPeopleEditMode_PageIndexChanging"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="BusinessEntityID" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MiddleName" HeaderText="MiddleName"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want the `page_load` to set the DataField attributes before setting the DataSource()/DataBind(), instead of writing them by myself in the .aspx page.

Is it possible to do that, or do I have to change the BoundFields?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You do not want to set **DataField** before binding. It'll override whatever changes you have make. Instead, you want to change them after binding. Tell use what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this in code side

```
C#
BoundField field = (BoundField)this.GridViewAllPeopleEditMode.Columns[0];
field.DataField = "To";

VB
Dim field As BoundField = DirectCast(Me.GridViewAllPeopleEditMode.Columns(0), BoundField)
field.DataField = "To"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but are you sure it will not point to the "edit" column, since i activated the AutoGenerateEditButton, which is created on the first column to the left of the Grid?

Comment: Yes it is point the first cell which is edit but it is just logic to change datafield dynamically you can use it with your requirement.

Comment: It worked, thanks, just change the (0) brackets in the C# code, with [0].